# ListView where each item is an ImageView with a radiobox and one item can be selected at a time?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, mobile

I'm tearing my hair out over this. I would like a ListView where each item in the list is an ImageView. I want each item to have a radio button next to it and only one item can be selected at a time (i.e. single choice mode). This code works fine for creating a list of text box with radio buttons:

```
    ListView listView = ...
    String [] value = {"test1","test2"};
    listView.setAdapter(
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,value
    ));
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

For my ImageView items, I implemented by own ArrayAdapter. In the getView method of my ArrayAdapter object, I load the follow xml file for each list row:

e.g.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:focusable="false"
  android:gravity="center"
>

<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
  android:paddingLeft="6dip"
  android:paddingRight="6dip"
  /> 

  <ImageView android:id="@+id/preview"
  android:layout_width="75dip" android:layout_height="100dip"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:focusable="false"
  /> 
  </RelativeLayout>
```

I copied the CheckedTextView item from the simple_list_item_single_choice.xml file used in the previous example. I assume that ListView must look for an item with id "text1" to use for displaying the selection status (I'm just guessing here as I cannot work out where the radio buttons are meant to come from). If I don't include the CheckedTextView item, I don't see any radio buttons at all.

When I use my custom adapter with the above xml file, I can see the radio buttons but selecting them does nothing. In addition, I've implemented the selection listener for the list view and this do not fire when I click items. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I can see the radio buttons but selecting them does nothing" -- what behavior are you expecting? "In addition, I've implemented the selection listener for the list view and this do not fire when I click items." -- the selection listener never fires when you click items. It fires when you select items using the navigational control (d-pad, trackball, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare: "what behavior are you expecting?" - I want the radioboxes to act like they do in the first example where only one radiobox can ever be toggled on at a time (i.e. across all list items). How can I do this while having an ImageView as part of my list items?

Comment: Thanks for the info -- that clarifies your question immensely. I don't have an answer for you, unfortunately. :-(

Comment: OK, thanks. All I can think to do now is to write a click listener for the ListView that will toggle the radiobox on the list item just selected and untoggle the radiobox on the previously selected list item. I would have hoped ListView could have kept track of this itself but I can't see what else I can do.